# How do I make a character shoot in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a game where my xwing shoots and kills the tiefighters. I just can not get the shooting image appear out of the xwing when I press the space bar. I know this question has been asked before, but I just can't get it. I am kinda new to python and pygame. Thanks!

```
import sys
import random
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((1280, 800))
display_width = 1280
display_height= 800

black= (0,0,0)
white= (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
blue_violet = (138,43,226)

bullets= []

xwingImg = pg.image.load('X-Wing.bmp').convert()
tieImg= pg.image.load('tiefighter.png').convert()
space=pg.image.load('space.jpg').convert()
xbullet = pg.image.load('bullet.png').convert()

BG_image = pg.image.load('space.jpg').convert()

def rot_center(image, angle):
    """rotate a Surface, maintaining position."""
    loc = image.get_rect().center  #rot_image is not defined 
    rot_sprite = pg.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    rot_sprite.get_rect().center = loc
    return rot_sprite

    # or return tuple: (Surface, Rect)
        # return rot_sprite, rot_sprite.get_rect()

def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    # Surfaces/images have a `get_rect` method which 
    # returns a rect with the dimensions of the image.
    player_rect = xwingImg.get_rect()
    player_rect.center = ( 640,400 )
    change_x = 0
    change_y = 0
    enemies = []
    spawn_counter = 30


    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == space:
                shot.play()
            for b in range(len(bullets)) :
                bullets [b] [0] -=10
            for bullet in bullets:
                if bullet [0] <0:
                    bullet.remove(bullet) 
                bullets.append ([event.pos[0], 500])

            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    change_x = 5
                if event.key == pg.K_w:
                    change_y = -5
                if event.key == pg.K_s:
                    change_y= 5
                if event.key == pg.K_a:
                    change_x = -5
            if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_d and change_x > 0:
                    change_x = 0
                if event.key == pg.K_a and change_x < 0:
                    change_x = 0
                if event.key == pg.K_w and change_y<0:
                    change_y=0
                if event.key == pg.K_s and change_y>0:
                    change_y=0



        # Spawn enemies if counter <= 0 then reset it.
        spawn_counter -= 1
        if spawn_counter <= 0:
            # Append an enemy rect. You can pass the position directly as an argument.
            enemies.append(tieImg.get_rect(topleft=(random.randrange(1280), -800 )))
            spawn_counter =  30


        # Update player_rect and enemies.
        player_rect.x += change_x
        player_rect.y += change_y
        for enemy_rect in enemies:
            enemy_rect.y += 5
            # Collision detection with pygame.Rect.colliderect.
            if player_rect.colliderect(enemy_rect):
                done = True

        # Draw everything.
        screen.blit(BG_image, (0,0))
        for bullet in bullets:
            screen.blit(xbullet, pg.Rect (bullet[0], bullet [1], 0, 0))

        for enemy_rect in enemies:
            screen.blit(tieImg, enemy_rect)
        screen.blit(xwingImg, player_rect)
        if player_rect.x >display_width:
            player_rect.x = 0
        if player_rect.x < 0:
            player_rect.x= 1280
        if player_rect.y>display_height:
            player_rect.y = 0
        if player_rect.y < 0:
            player_rect.y= 800


        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(40)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better to use [pygame sprites](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=de#section_13) and sprite groups instead of lists of rects. (Chapter 12 explains how classes work.) To shoot things with rects, you need to do a bit more yourself.

First shoot single bullet rects (append them to the `bullets` list) by pressing space. Add these three lines to your event loop:

```
if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
        bullets.append(xbullet.get_rect(center=player_rect.midtop))
```

Move the bullets in the while loop:

```
for bullet in bullets:
    bullet.y -= 4
```

And blit them:

```
for bullet in bullets:
    screen.blit(xbullet, bullet)
```

Now comes the difficult part. We have to check which enemy collided with a bullet and then filter the `enemies` list, so that it only contains the surviving enemies.

```
# We'll use the hit_enemies list to check which enemy has survived.
hit_enemies = []
for enemy_rect in enemies:
    enemy_rect.y += 5
    # Collision detection with player.
    if player_rect.colliderect(enemy_rect):
        done = True
    # Collision detection with bullets.
    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.colliderect(enemy_rect):
            hit_enemies.append(enemy_rect)

# Filter the destroyed enemies out. We create a new list and
# append the surviving enemies to it.
survivors = []
for enemy in enemies:
    if enemy not in hit_enemies:
        survivors.append(enemy)
enemies = survivors  # Now `enemies` is the list of survivors.
# You can also do it in one line with a list comprehension.
# enemies = [enemy for enemy in enemies if enemy not in hit_enemies]
```

You have to do the same for the bullets to remove them. Also,  the enemies and bullets should be filtered out if they leave the screen, otherwise the lists keep growing the whole time.

Here's the complete example:

```
import sys
import random
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((1280, 800))
display_width = 1280
display_height = 800

xwingImg = pg.image.load('X-Wing.bmp').convert()
tieImg= pg.image.load('tiefighter.png').convert()
space=pg.image.load('space.jpg').convert()
xbullet = pg.image.load('bullet.png').convert()
BG_image = pg.image.load('space.jpg').convert()


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    player_rect = xwingImg.get_rect()
    player_rect.center = (640, 400)
    change_x = 0
    change_y = 0
    enemies = []
    bullets = []
    spawn_counter = 30

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    bullets.append(xbullet.get_rect(center=player_rect.midtop))
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    change_x = 5
                if event.key == pg.K_w:
                    change_y = -5
                if event.key == pg.K_s:
                    change_y= 5
                if event.key == pg.K_a:
                    change_x = -5
            if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_d and change_x > 0:
                    change_x = 0
                if event.key == pg.K_a and change_x < 0:
                    change_x = 0
                if event.key == pg.K_w and change_y<0:
                    change_y=0
                if event.key == pg.K_s and change_y>0:
                    change_y=0

        # Spawn enemies if counter <= 0 then reset it.
        spawn_counter -= 1
        if spawn_counter <= 0:
            # Append an enemy rect. You can pass the position directly as an argument.
            enemies.append(tieImg.get_rect(topleft=(random.randrange(1280), -100)))
            spawn_counter =  30

        # Update player_rect.
        player_rect.x += change_x
        player_rect.y += change_y

        # Update bullets.
        for bullet in bullets:
            bullet.y -= 4

        # Detect collisions and move the enemies.
        hit_enemies = []
        for enemy_rect in enemies:
            enemy_rect.y += 5
            # Collision detection with pygame.Rect.colliderect.
            if player_rect.colliderect(enemy_rect):
                done = True
            # Collision detection with bullets.
            for bullet in bullets:
                if bullet.colliderect(enemy_rect):
                    hit_enemies.append(enemy_rect)

        # Filter the destroyed enemies out.
        survivors = []
        for enemy in enemies:
            if enemy not in hit_enemies:
                survivors.append(enemy)
        enemies = survivors  # Now `enemies` is the list of survivors.

        # Draw everything.
        screen.blit(BG_image, (0,0))
        for bullet in bullets:
            screen.blit(xbullet, bullet)

        for enemy_rect in enemies:
            screen.blit(tieImg, enemy_rect)
        screen.blit(xwingImg, player_rect)
        if player_rect.x >display_width:
            player_rect.x = 0
        if player_rect.x < 0:
            player_rect.x= 1280
        if player_rect.y>display_height:
            player_rect.y = 0
        if player_rect.y < 0:
            player_rect.y= 800

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(40)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are testing this

```
if event.type == space:
```

but

```
space = pg.image.load('space.jpg').convert()
```

so the `event.type` will never match that.

You need something like this:

```
if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
```

like you are testing the other keys.

Your next problem is that you haven't assigned `shot` anywhere

Comment: I did this, but I am very new to python and pygame. I don't know what to do. Could you give me an example of how to do this?